# How do I limit the amount of login retries in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a login form I have in django to only allow three login attempts before redirecting to a "login help" page.  I am currently using the builtin "django.contrib.auth.views.login" view with a custom template.  How do I force it to redirect to another page after n failed login attempts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's actually a project out there which provides a Django middleware to do just this, called [`django-axes`](https://github.com/philipn/django-axes).  Simply install it with the instructions provided and then set `AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT` to the number of login attempts you want before a record is created for the failed logins.  You'll still have to check this record when you want to lock someone out, however.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I chose dotty's answer because it was closer to the method I ended up using.  Part of the issue was my own inexperience with Python and Django and as such I didn't have enough knowledge to ask the right question.  I think your answer would have been just as good if not better if I wanted something with that many features, and I may well end upo using it when I am more familiar with the framework.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to let you know that there was a solution out there already that could potentially work.  I didn't know it existed either so I learned something in the process too!

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes

Answer (score 0):

i use `django-brake` and memcached

```
@ratelimit(field='email', method='POST', rate='5/m')
@ratelimit(field='email', method='POST', rate='10/h')
@ratelimit(field='email', method='POST', rate='20/d')
def login_failure(request, login_form):
    """
    Increment cache counters, 403 if over limit.
    """
    was_limited = getattr(request, 'limited', False)
    if was_limited:
        limits = getattr(request, 'limits', [])
        login_form.full_clean()
        login_form._errors.setdefault(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ErrorList())\
            .append('accout locked, try '+ str(limits[0]['period']) + ' seconds later')
        return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'form': login_form})


def login(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        next = request.GET.get('next', '')
        return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'next': next})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        # check first 
        from brake.utils import get_limits
        limits = get_limits(request, 'login_failure', 'email', [60, 3600, 86400])
        if limits:
            login_form.full_clean()
            login_form._errors.setdefault(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ErrorList())\
                .append('accout locked, try '+ str(limits[0]['period']) + ' seconds later')
            return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'form': login_form})

        if login_form.is_valid():

                email = login_form.cleaned_data['email']
                submit_pwd = login_form.cleaned_data['password']

                user = authenticate(username=email, password=submit_pwd)

                if user is None:
                     # 
                    res = login_failure(request, login_form)
                    if res is None:
                        login_form._errors.setdefault(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ErrorList()).append('password wrong')
                        res = render(request, 'user/login.html', {'form': login_form})
                    return res

                ...
                login etc...
        else:

        ...
```

Comment: django-brake is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score -9):

You could save a session if the user has failed to login.

```
request.SESSION['login_tries'] = 1
```

and if they fail to login again

```
request.SESSioN['login_tries'] = 2
```

If the session becomes equal to the amount of login tries you want them tho have, then do something.

Comment: The session will only exist if the client is sending Cookie headers, which a brute force attacker will not be doing. It would be better to link login attempts with a specific user account, or a specific client (or both).